# Add each value in one column to each value in second column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, multiple-columns, array-formulas

Would like to have each value in one column added to each value in a second column to created a compounded array.  Was thinking I could use ARRAYFORMULA for this, but not that easy, it appears.  I want the result column automatically expanded like ARRAYFORMULA does because the number of rows can change and be unequal between Col 1 and Col 2:

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | Result
------+-------+-------
10    |   1   | 11
------+-------+-------
20    |   2   | 12
------+-------+-------
30    |   3   | 13
------+-------+-------
40    |       | 21
------+-------+-------
50    |       | 22
------+-------+-------
      |       | 23
------+-------+-------
      |       | 31
------+-------+-------
      |       | 32
------+-------+-------
      |       | 33
------+-------+-------
etc...
```

I could write a script that creates this ONEDIT() when an indicator value changes, but would prefer a formula.

Thanks!

Comment: You effectively want a new query every time a cell is edited, and the query to be updated and fill in new rows.  I think it could be done with formulas but with one problem;  you would need enough formulas in the third column to cover all possible permutations, which changes.  So you'd need to fill lots more rows with formulas, than you would ever need, or inject the formulas with code every time.  But if you are going to use code, it's sort of pointless to use the formulas.

Comment: I don't want to use code and would rather use the Google ARRAYFORMULA or some derivation that allows me a single formula that automatically expands the results column.  Code is too permanent.  Formula allows for easier changes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after goofing around for a while, I figured it out.  Perhaps this will help someone else or spur someone on to a more elegant answer than this.  In Google Sheets, put this formula in the top cell (C2 in the example table) and the rest of the values will be automatically expanded and added properly:

=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(JOIN(",",$A1:$A10),COUNT($B1:$B10)),",")))+ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(JOIN(",",(REPT(","&$B1:$B10,COUNT($A1:$A10)))),",")))))

This assumed that each column could have up to 9 rows.  Can obviously adjust the number of rows based on the range that you specify for each column.  This takes the values in each column, combines them into an array which it repeats and joins/splits or joins and then repeats and splits... to create the correct combination.  One formula that automatically expands and is flexible without scripting.  Please share a better way to do this, if there is.